# Creating a Windows 8.1 install USB on a Mac - for install on an Intel NUC (non-Mac)

Tags: windows-8, mac, installation, boot-camp

How do you create a Windows 8.1 install USB using a Mac (OS X 10.9.5), to install on a non-Mac, an Intel NUC?

Is this the same process as using Bootcamp to create a Windows installation USB? Does it matter which Bootcamp version is used?

Answer (score 0):

Bootcamp takes a CD image of windows and makes it bootable on a USB disk. Any recent version should be fine. The trick, and what boot camp provides, is just in making the USB flash disk bootable and able to bootstrap the CD media. Alternatives to boot camp exist (unetbootin being one example) which do the same thing, it is really just a question of how the boot strap process works and what type of BIOS you are targeting.

The official approach to creating a USB boot disk for windows is to use the Windows "Create Media" tool. The advantage of this approach is not needing a CD, although this requires having windows or at least windows in a VM. You can get the tool at:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Comment: Do you know if bootcamp creates an image that is only usable for macs or if it will work for a general non-Mac PC?

Comment: My understanding is that it should work for both.